# What factors decide which team wins when the clock runs out in Capture the Flag/Control Points?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was in the map Doublecross and we just barely managed to tie the score at 2 as the clock ran out, but we still got the Humiliation mode, instead of both teams getting it.

Also I think Control Points decides its winner at a clock-out by which team has fewer points controlled. Which I think I can understand because it rewards the defenders for holding off the other team successfully. I don't know if this is really the case though.

Answer (score 3):

If time runs out on a symmetrical game mode due to the server's map time running out, the scores displayed are based on the number of rounds won by each team while on that map. If the one team won more rounds on the current map, they get the victory.

Control Points is considered a draw if the game ends due to time (unless sudden death mode is enabled), regardless of who controls the most points. Again, the humiliation & victory is based on previous rounds.

Answer (score 3):

The results of a time out in CTF and symmetrical CP are dependant on server settings, so there can be several different results:

- Both teams stalemate.
- Whichever team scored the most points on the scoreboard during that round wins.
- The game goes to Sudden Death. Whoever wins Sudden Death wins; if that's also a time out, it's a stalemate.

Comment: the second point might have been what that server had. The opposing team managed to set up a huge engineer nest (around 5 or 6 engies) above our side's building, and nobody could take it out. they probably had way more points.